# Windows phone 8 admob white surrounding in Landscape‏

Tags: admob, landscape, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

When I have a **Admob Adview** with this code:

```
<GoogleAds:AdView AdUnitID="ca-app-pub-xxxxxx" 
                                    Format="Banner" 
                                    ReceivedAd="AdView_ReceivedAd" 
                                    FailedToReceiveAd="AdView_FailedToReceiveAd" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    />
```

But when I start my app in **Landscape** mode I get a white surrounding around my AdView. Sometimes the **AdView** fills the complete size, but some ads are too small like this: